# Stray start tag td && Stray end tag td. w3c validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation

My HTML is as as below.

```html
<div class="plan-row">
    <div class="plan-cell en">100MB</div>
    <div class="plan-cell en">4GB</div>
    <div class="plan-cell hide-sm en">
        <td lang="en">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </td>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check my website validation in `validator.w3.org` i got this error

> Stray start tag `td`.

And

> Stray end tag `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<td>` tag defines a standard cell in an HTML table.

Because that your `td` element is not inside a table, but inside a `div` element, you are getting the error of `stray start tag`.